# query on mysql not returning expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image]

This is my database data. I want to query a record with

> $period = 3
>
> $dependent + 1 = 1
>
> $birstat = 2
>
> $netpay = 10741.2

My query is :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM af_hris_masterfile_tax_table WHERE "
. " payroll_period = :period AND "
. "status = :birstat AND "
. "dependent = :dependent AND "
. "(cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND :name <= cast(max_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) OR cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND LOWER(max_compensation) = 'above') ");
//        . "(min_compensation <= :name AND :name <= max_compensation) OR (min_compensation <= :name AND LOWER(max_compensation) = 'above') ");
$stmt->bindValue(":name", ($netpay), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(":dependent", ($dependent + 1), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(":period", $period, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(":birstat", $birstat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

With this query and with the set parameter I am expecting to get the record with `sys_id 111` Because `10741.2` is greater than `7917.01` but is less than `12500`

***But the record i am getting is record with sys_id 112***

Any idea what i have mis-looked.

Any idea is appreciated

**UPDATE**

As per suggestion

```
. "(cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND :name1 <= cast(max_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) OR cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name2 AND LOWER(max_compensation) = 'above') ");
//        . "(min_compensation <= :name AND :name <= max_compensation) OR (min_compensation <= :name AND LOWER(max_compensation) = 'above') ");
        $stmt->bindValue(":name", floatval($netpay), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name1", floatval($netpay), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name2", floatval($netpay), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**UPDATE**
When i use

```
. "(  min_compensation <= :name AND :name <= max_compensation ) ");
 $stmt->bindValue(":name", ($netpay));
```

I am getting `sys_id` `[{"sysid":"106","min":"1.01","max":"2083","payrollperiod":"3","status":"2","dependent":"1",....`

Comment: you're using the same named placeholder often `:name` and in PDO, you need to use different ones.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i used `:name1 , :name2` for the other values but same result im getting `[{"sysid":"112","min":"12500.01","max":"Above",......`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here, but shouldn't those `PDO::PARAM_STR` be `PDO::PARAM_INT`?

Comment: Also, your row has `Above` with an uppercase "A", yet you're checking with `= 'above'` having a lowercase "a"; two different animals here. That's probably why it's failing you now. Edit: I think I'm wrong here, since you're using `LOWER`. TBH, I don't know why your query is failing, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how would you have done the query if it where you i really cant figure out why it is not working